# What does "22/30" mean when talking taxes and selling an apartment?

Tags: taxes, real-estate, selling, sweden

I really tried to think through this and search before asking. I hate having to ask questions.

[On this webpage, on the Swedish IRS' website.](https://www.skatteverket.se/privat/fastigheterochbostad/forsaljningavbostad/raknautvinstforlustochskatt/forsaljningavbostadsratt.4.233f91f71260075abe8800033855.html)

It says:

> Om du säljer en privatbostadsrätt med vinst ska 22/30 av vinsten beskattas. En förlust får dras av med 50 procent.

This, in English, means:

> If you sell a private (owned) apartment with profits, 22/30 of the profits are to be taxed. A loss can be reduced by 50 percent.

They go out of their way to avoid "percent" for the most important part. Why? I have no idea. I've never heard or seen "22/30" in any context, and it makes no sense to me.

Some other webpage in English claims that it means 73.33333333%... [Source.](https://researchmaniacs.com/Math/Percentage/What-Is-22/30-As-A-Percent.html)

Why would they mix this bizarre way of typing a percentage with the actual percentage in the same paragraph, and in other places on the same webpage? There must be a reason for this.

And if they really are going to take 73.3% of the profits, that is absolutely insane and there won't be almost anything left at all. They cannot possibly mean that. Capital gains taxes are like "30 % of the profits" in Sweden, and I assumed that selling an apartment would be at least the same or less than that. 70+%? That simply cannot be right.

Comment: The page doesn't `mix this bizarre way of typing a percentage with the actual percentage`. The 50% refers to what happens if you make a loss, not a profit; it's a different number applied in a different situation. I agree it's bizarre that all other places use percentages, but that specific one is a fraction.

Comment: Why legislatures or regulatory bodies phrase a specific law or regulation in a specific way is generally a political question

Comment: '"why not use a percentage".  The use of 22/30 as the rate provides a higher taxable base than the percentage of 73.3% when the gain is very large.  Every additional 'penny' paid in taxes is good for the government - LOL

Answer (score 5):

I agree that the 22/30 seems odd where all other fractions are expressed as percentages.

Looking at [this KPMG site](https://home.kpmg/xx/en/home/insights/2021/06/sweden-taxation-of-international-executives.html) makes things a little clearer:

> 22/30 of principal residence gains are taxed at a flat rate of 30 percent. Taxation may be deferred if a substitute home is bought within the EU and if certain criteria are met. Tax of 0.5 percent of the deferred gain is levied annually.

So the actual taxation is 30% of 22/30, not 73.33%.  And if another house is bought within the EU (with some conditions), it doesn't apply.

As KateGregory says in the comments, stating it as 22/30 makes the overall tax rate easy to see:

> 22/30 x 30/100 = 22/100

Comment: and if it's 30% of 22/30ths, that means the actual tax is 22% of the gain, yes? Easy math.

Comment: @KateGregory Good point! It does make the math easy.

Comment: ... sure the math is easy, but why couldn't they just say 22%?

Comment: Because the 22% is derived from multiple tax components,  The first is only 22/30 of the profit from a privately owned apartment is taxed.  That taxable amount would be different for a different category of ownership or property.  The second component is the 30%, and again that flat rate is the rate to apply for the type of return being taxed.  The 22% is just the rate that was derived when you selected the type of property and ownership.

Comment: It does still apply if you buy another house. The payment of the tax is _deferred_, not waived. As the quoted website says, you have to pay 0.5% per year, so you’ll pay it all off over 44 years.

Comment: "Tax of 0.5 percent of the deferred gain is levied annually". This tax was removed from January 1st, 2021. https://skatteverket.se/privat/fastigheterochbostad/forsaljningavbostad/uppskov.4.6d02084411db6e252fe80009532.html#!/start